# Is XML a light-weight data base or is it a document?

Tags: xml, database, document

I have always considered XML to be the source of data, not the presentation of data, however I have worked with marketing people that like selling the idea to customers that XML is a document that they can view in a browser. I try explaining that it is merely the data component, and that the view is separate, but I have had limited success with this approach. Am I far off in my assumption that XML is a data store?

Comment: XML is a syntax. What else you call it depends on how you use it.

Comment: I'm wondering what sort of customers will be ready to view and use an XML data in a browser.

Comment: @MainMa you would be surprised, sometimes it's been old school COBOL programmer that is still hanging on out there ;-)

Comment: XML is not light weight, JSON is. something like... fuzzy wuzzy uh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML is a structured way to store data. It can be both database and document.

It's a database in the sense that it contains data which match a certain format, and you can read or modify this data.

It is a document in a way that it stores some data in a file, like Word document or Photoshop image.

Of course, it is **not** a presentation of data, and for any non-IT person, XML must be presented in order to be used.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct: **XML is not a presentation language.** It is designed to store data.

However, that doesn't prevent you from leveraging additional technologies (such as [XSL](http://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) and [CSS](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/)) to format and present the data that is stored in an XML document.

Comment: To add to Cody Gray's statement here is a link to XSL information..http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Comment: Downvoters, please give reasons. Do you think XML is a presentation language? Do you disagree that you can format and present the data that an XML file contains using other technologies?

Comment: I agree, came once and then everyone was set back to zero.. probably hoping their answer will get to the top with one vote...

Answer (score 3):

Well these days you'd be hard pressed to make any concise statement about what XML is and isn't or what it should and shouldn't be used for.  There are examples of XML used for data exchange, app configuration, data storage, you name it.  And that's without considering adaptations such as OML, XAML etc.

It might be helpful to look back at the origins of XML, such as [this article](http://www.nytimes.com/library/tech/00/06/biztech/technology/07mark.html), alongside some of the [criticisms](http://news.cnet.com/XML-too-inefficient-for-the-Web/2009-1081_3-984221.html) often raised.

And here's an interesting quote from the author of [Effective XML](http://weblogs.asp.net/sbchatterjee/archive/2003/11/22/39257.aspx).

> XML is not a database. It was never
>   meant to be a database. It is never
>   going to be a database. Relational
>   databases are proven technology with
>   more than 20 years of implementation
>   experience. They are solid, stable,
>   useful products. They are not going
>   away. XML is a very useful technology
>   for moving data between different
>   databases or between databases and
>   other programs. However, it is not
>   itself a database. Don't use it like
>   one.

Comment: I understand the quote, but do not agree with the author's thought that a database is always relational...

Answer (score 2):

As the name says, XML is (an extensible) **markup** (language). You can use it for documents, to store plain data in it, for for god knows what (strictly speaking, all of these are some kind of information). It *is* commonly used for data, yes. But I think it's rarely superior to extremely lightweight data formats such as JSON or YAML - trees are very general powerful, so they can represent most data with relatively little bending, but they're not the most natural representation for most data. Think of lists or key-value pairs... you have to model those as lots of leaves or lots of small branches with two leaves each.

It's not a database in the traditional sense, at least not an efficient one. Think about it: To get data from it, you parse it completely, build a large tree while doing so, and then search that tree to get to the information you want. Yes, that's because it's so flexible, but that's exactly the problem. Or, of course, you use SAX and use less memory - but that's still linear search.

Although it can be useful to store data in a database-agnostic matter - again because of its flexibility.

Comment: +1 for XML not being a database in the technical sense. XML is far more useful as a serialization technology, rather than to use as a real-time database.

Answer (score 0):

XML is a data format. HTML is an approach to use XML for documents (by giving the data a specific meaning). CSS is used for styling HTML. XML itself does not do any of this. It just stores the information. Some browsers render plain XML as a highlighted tree, but that is not a property of XML. It is what the browser does with it. You *can* add CSS, etc to XML, but that does not ensure that it is displayed like that. XML itself is just a data container.